# conditionally multiply a vector by another r

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have the following vector

```
trans<- c(-2,3,10,-5,-2,56,0)
```

and I want to multiply each element by a choice of two vectors depending on whether the initial number is positive or negative

```
negtrans<-c(1,2,3)
postrans<-c(4,5,6,7)
```

the result should look like this 
-2
12
50
-10
-6
336
0

the key here is to keep the order intact

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is

```
unsplit(Map(`*`, split(trans, trans>=0), 
               list(negtrans, postrans)),trans>=0)
#[1]  -2  12  50 -10  -6 336   0
```

Comment: But slow -- see my speed test.

Answer (score 2):

Just multiply the corresponding entries with negtrans or postrans as required.

```
i <- which(trans < 0)
trans[i] <- trans[i] * negtrans
trans[-i] <- trans[-i] * postrans
```

However you will have a problem if the lengths of i and negtrans don't match.

Answer (score 2):

I like akrun's answer for form, but it turns out not so great.

EDIT:  here's a pretty dumb solution which is essentially the same as konvas' :

```
trans[trans<0]<-trans[trans<0]*negtrans
trans[trans>0]<-trans[trans>0]*postrans
```

And here's how it worked out:

```
trans<-sample(-100:100,1e5,rep=TRUE)
negtrans<-1:1e3
postrans<-1e4:100e4

    Unit: microseconds
                              expr     min      lq  median      uq
   carl(trans, negtrans, postrans)   6.415   7.697   8.126  11.546
  akrun(trans, negtrans, postrans) 204.832 210.390 223.220 234.337
 konvas(trans, negtrans, postrans)   5.560   5.987   6.415  10.263
     max neval
  29.934     5
 376.308     5
  15.395     5
```

Comment: Try this example with your code `trans <- c(-1, 3, 5, 7, 8,10,-2);  negtrans <- c(1,3); postrans <- 4:8` After
 running my code and konvas's code it gives `[1] -1 12 25 42 56 80 -6` while yours 
give `[1] -1 12 15 35  8 60 -6 -7  3 40`

Comment: @akrun - I apologize - I got halfway thru developing this and completely walked off the map.  I'll delete my code and look for something that's correct.